# JS redirect based on browser language

Tags: javascript

I'm using this test code:

```
<script type="type/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function(){
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    if (userLang == "fr") {
        window.location.href = "www.facebook.com"
    }
    else if(userLang == "de"){
       window.location.href = "www.facebook.com"
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "www.google.com"
    }
});
</script>
```

But nothing happens. I must be dumb?

You can see it here:
URL removed

Comment: I personally hate automatic redirections based on some retrieved language option or location, and most likely I'm not the only one. Please provide something a visitor can select a language from, manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a protocol. Also, here's a suggestion for a cleaner approach replacing the series of if's.

```js
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
var urls = {
    'fr': 'http://www.facebook.com',
    'de': 'http://www.facebook.com',
};
var defaultUrl = 'http://www.google.com';

var url = urls[userLang] ?? defaultUrl;
console.log(url);

//window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: It's not working I updated my URL with your code. I removed the comment of course.

Comment: Thanks it's working! I removed the type=""

Answer (score 1):

```
// Better code in terms of lines of code and avoiding if conditions.

const sites = {
'fr': 'https://www.facebook.com',
'de': 'https://www.google.com',
};

const userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
window.location.href = sites[userLang];
```

Comment: Better code in terms of avoiding multiple conditions and number of lines.. as posted in the question @MWO

Answer (score 0):

Please give it a try like this:

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function(){
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    if (userLang == "fr") {
        window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com"
    }
    else if(userLang == "de"){
       window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com"
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.com"
    }
});
</script>
```

And find this documentation [MDN HTML Script tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) regarding how to use the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

This must not be the cleanest way, but I needed to redirect by the browser language, and the variable `navigator.language` usually has a value like `en-US` then my solution based on other's answers was:

```js
<script>

let userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
if (userLang.includes("en")) {
    window.location.href = '/en/';  
} else if (userLang.includes("es")) {
    window.location.href = '/es/';  
} else {
    window.location.href = '/en/';  
}

</script>
```